# phpmyadmin select data from multiple tables using php

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

hello i am trying to do a select query from multiple tables and I made variables for the tables names and it works if I removed the variables and put the tables names instead what to do?

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'student_list';
 $table_name1 = $wpdb->prefix . 'courses';
 $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'registration';  



$registrations = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT registration_id , $table_name1.course_id ,$table_name.student_id ,$table_name1.name, $table_name1.course_name ,$table_name1.course_code FROM $table_name ,$table_name1, $table_name2 WHERE $table_name2.course_id = $table_name1.course_id and $table_name2.student_id = $table_name.student_id");
```

Comment: Maybe try without the prefix. just `$table_name = 'student_list';`

Comment: i need to add it so if a WordPress user used the wp prefix it will add
the prefix worked in other places

Comment: Ok... but the prefix is only used at the database-name not the tables itself, or am i wrong? Could you edit your question and show the working case without variables, please?

Comment: $registrations = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT registration_id , courses.course_id ,wp_student_list.student_id ,wp_student_list.name, courses.course_name , courses.course_code FROM `registration` ,`courses`, `wp_student_list` WHERE registration.course_id = courses.course_id and registration.student_id = wp_student_list.student_id");

Comment: See, you don't use the prefix -> that's why it works ;)

Comment: i know but i need to add it

Comment: Are you sure? Could you explain more detailed what you are trying to accomplish? I think you have an thinking-error there...

Comment: i added the prefix because there is a button in the Wordpress that unable a prefix in every table so the prefix will add a  the text needed in front the table name